# Server hosting only allows authorised IP's for database access

Tags: android, mysql, networking

I'm working on an Android app that will be uploading and downloading data from a MYSQL database from many locations.
My understanding is that IP addresses will be created dynamically and the server will have to communicate data with different IP's every day for the application to be used anywhere.

My database is currently being hosted with Tsohost.com, I am able to communicate with the database, however, each IP has to be manually authorised (https://i.stack.imgur.com/441H2.png).
How can I get around this problem? Is this problem unique to Tsohost, or do I need to create some kind of interface. Sorry if I've made any wrong assumptions, I'm not very good at networking/internet programming.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app should communicate with your web site. That site in turn will communicate with DB. this is how you will be using 1 IP (web site IP) to access the database.

It is bad practice to allow end users have direct access to your database - you;ll have to hard code DB password in your app!

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, Thanks! What language would you suggest I program this in? Would I be right in saying php?

Comment: It is your preference. PHP is one of many languages web servers support.